# Delete API not working while the file it needs to delete is present on the server, in JMeter

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to test a delete API which deletes a file from the server.

So, First I upload that file and then deletes it, please refer the image

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So the Upload API is getting success
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

But the Delete API is getting failed with Error 404 not found, though I checked that file is present there on the server

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

We can see that file abc is present there on frontend, so it was uploaded there successfully.
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

This is I'm inputting in JMeter
[![enter image description here][5]][5]
This is the request header manager for that API
[![enter image description here][6]][6]

This is how it is called in Network tab
[![enter image description here][7]][7]
[![enter image description here][8]][8]

So could you please help me with this API, like how can I get it working?
Or guide me that what I'm doing wrong here with this delete API?

Note: I've added a HTTP Requests defaults on thread so, please don't get confused with the screen shot where there is no host details.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PesFs.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGJDE.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpANO.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SmIr.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwi6O.png
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd1td.png
[7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TADQK.png
[8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dErUU.png

Comment: Try add a timer/pause action between requests to see if it's timing issue

Comment: Its of no use tried it, is there any other way ?